# SWT- setSize and setBounds doesn't work on label

Tags: java, swt

I have a label. Sometimes, the text in it has overflow and doesn't show in the label. So, I would like to change the height of the label and also would like to when it has overflow it shows in its below line. How can I do that?

```
composite = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
composite.setLayout(new GridLayout());
GridData data = new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL);    
Group grpModelProperties = new Group(composite, SWT.SHADOW_IN);
grpModelProperties.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
grpModelProperties.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false));
Label l2 = new Label(grpModelProperties, SWT.NULL);
new Label(grpModelProperties, SWT.NONE);
l2.setLayoutData(data);
l2.setText("Text: " + Text);    
//l2.setBounds(0, 0, 470, 200);   
//l2.setSize( 470, 400 );
```

Comment: You can't mix layouts and setSize/setBounds. The layout will override these calls.

Comment: @greg-449 what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the style `SWT.WRAP` to the label constructor to specify that the text should automatically wrap in a new line if there is not enough horizontal space:

```
Label l2 = new Label(grpModelProperties, SWT.WRAP);
```

Comment: when I use `SWT.WRAP`, the part of my text doesn't show at all.

Comment: @BA works for me using your code, you should create a [mcve] showing the problem.

Comment: I use this code in the `createDialogArea` function of a class which extends `TitleAreaDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of changes to make for this to work. First, you'll need to use the `SWT.WRAP` style bit in the `Label` constructor. In your case:

```
Label l2 = new Label(grpModelProperties, SWT.WRAP);
```

*(As a side note, if you don't want a style set, you should use `SWT.NONE`, not `SWT.NULL`)*.

Also, you'll need to set a `widthHint` on the layout data for the top level element, otherwise your dialog will expand to accommodate the full width of the text. In your code:

```
composite.setLayout(new GridLayout());
GridData compositeGridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
compositeGridData.widthHint = 200;
composite.setLayoutData(compositeGridData);
```

Slightly cleaned up, but your code should ultimately look something like this:

```
@Override
protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
    composite = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
    composite.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
    data.widthHint = 200;
    composite.setLayoutData(data);

    Group groupModelProperties = new Group(composite, SWT.SHADOW_IN);
    groupModelProperties.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
    groupModelProperties.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false));

    Label label = new Label(groupModelProperties, SWT.WRAP);
    label.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    label.setText("Text: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. This is a really long line of text that should wrap into a new line.");

    return composite;
}
```

[image]